# Custom Callout menu display the document metadata , when item is opened

Tags: 2013, 2010, 2016, callouts

How to display all the metadata for a document in a callout menu  ?
I am looking to display all the metadata for a document when you click and open a list item call out option . By default , the office Web apps preview is displayed for an document library item . 
I want to hide this office preview and display the metdata for the user in the content section .

Comment: Look at the last two links from Rishabh Shukla's answer here: sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184451/adding-comments-to-a-list-item/184457.